Show the bound $|\operatorname{Li}_s(z)|=O(\log^s z )$
Provided that $s\in \mathbb {C}$ is not a negative integer, how do you show that
$$|\operatorname{Li}_s(z)|=O(\log^s z )$$
as $|z|\to +\infty$, where the implied constant is $1/\Gamma (s+1)$?

I've read some sources which mention equivalent bounds, but either the conditions on $s$ differ, or I can't fully understand. I will summarize the proofs along with my questions (in my notation) below. I should add that I am open to any other methods of showing the claim.

Section $11$ of "The Computation of Polylogarithms" by David C. Wood. Using the integral representation of $\operatorname {Li}_s(-{\rm e}^{z})$, splitting the integration about the singularity of the integrand, and making a few substitutions, Wood arrives at
$$\operatorname {Li}_s(-{\rm e}^{z})+(-1)^s\operatorname{Li}_s(-{\rm e}^{-z}) =-\frac{z^{s}}{\Gamma(s+1)}+\frac{1}{\Gamma (s)}\int _0^{+\infty }\frac{(z-x)^{s-1}-(x-z)^{s-1}}{{\rm e}^x+1}\ {\rm d} x.$$ Now he notes that if $s\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, expanding the numerator and integrating term by term gives a closed form. Otherwise, the binomial theorem holds only for $x <|\sigma|$ where $\sigma =\mathrm{Re}(z)$, but for $\sigma\gg 1$ the integrand is so small beyond this point that the error incurred is $O({\rm e}^{-z})$. The second term on the left is of the same order, so it may be dropped, giving
$$\operatorname{Li}_s(-{\rm e}^z)\sim -2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \eta (2k)\frac{z^{s-2k}}{\Gamma(s-2k+1)}+O({\rm e}^{-z})\tag{?}$$
for large $\mathrm{Re}(z)$, where $\eta(2k)$ is the Dirichlect eta function. The claim follows after similar computations on $\operatorname{Li}_s({\rm e}^{z})$ to deduce,
$\operatorname{Li}_s(\pm {\rm e}^{z})\sim -\frac{z^{s}}{\Gamma(s+1)}$
for large $\mathrm{Re}(z)$, then finally letting $z\mapsto \log z$.

Fortunately, this is proof holds for all $s\in \mathbb C\setminus \mathbb{Z}_-$, but I do not follow how Wood applied the Binomial theorem and deduce Eqn$(?)$. Also, how did they size the "second term on the left"?


Corollary $1.3.$ of "Resurgence of the fractional polylogarithms" by Ovidiu Costin, Stavros Garoufalidis. Fix $s\in\mathbb C$ with $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$ and $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ with $z=|z|{\rm e}^{i\theta}$. Using the integral representation of $\operatorname{Li}_s(z)$ and making some substitutions, they arrive at
$$\operatorname{Li}_s(z)\Gamma(s)=\int _{1/z-1}^{{\rm e} ^{-i\theta }\infty}\frac{(\log z+\log (x+1))^{s}}{x^2}\ {\rm d} x. \tag{??}$$
Then the integration is split into $|x|\le |\log z|$ and $|\log z| \le |x|$. The claim follows after sizing both integrals as $\frac{\log ^s z}{s}(1+o(1))$ and $O(\log ^{s-1} z)$ respectively, for large $|z|$.

How is the substitution (from $s$ to $t$ in the paper) being performed here? I don't see how ${\rm e} ^{-i\theta}\infty$ is the upper bound. Also it is claimed that this proof only holds for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$, but is there a way to extend this?


Section $1.3.$ of "Polylogarithmes" by Joseph Oesterlé. This paper is written in French which I have very little knowledge of. However, I can tell that the inversion formula
$$\operatorname{Li}_k(z)+(-1)^k\operatorname{Li}_k(1/z)=-\frac{(2\pi i )^k}{k!}B_{k}\left(\frac{\log z}{2\pi i}\right),$$
where $k$ is a positive integer and $B_k(.)$ is the $k$-th Bernoulli polynomial, is stated with a brief proof sketch after. Then Oesterlé notes that in particular, $|\operatorname{Li}_k (z)|=O(\log^k |z|)$.

Sadly, this proof only holds for positive integer parameters, and seems hard to extend to the complex plane. Is it possible?

It might be better if you split this into several questions.

@zkutch: Controversial. Such questions would be too closely related. Moreover, whenever I need a reference to something like this, I would prefer a single link rather than a bunch of.

Of course,
@metamorphy,
you can argue about everything. But it is easier to answer one question than many - look at the practical result. As for links, if there are many and you don't like them, take one. I prefer many, even, frankly, all possible ones.

There is a typo in the formula by Wood. If you look at the previous line, it should read
$$
\operatorname{Li}_s ( - {\rm e}^z ) + ( - 1)^s \operatorname{Li}_s ( - {\rm e}^{ - z} ) =  - \frac{{z^s }}{{\Gamma (s + 1)}} + \frac{1}{{\Gamma (s)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{(z - x)^{s - 1}  - (z + x)^{s - 1} }}{{{\rm e}^x  + 1}}{\rm d}x} .
$$
Using the binomial series, we find
$$
(z - x)^{s - 1}  - (z + x)^{s - 1}  =  - 2z^{s - 1} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma (s)}}{{\Gamma (s - 2k + 1)\Gamma (2k)}}\frac{{x^{2k - 1} }}{{z^{2k - 1} }}} , \quad x<|z|.
$$
Term-by-term integration and the integral representation of the Dirichlet eta function then yield
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Li}_s ( - {\rm e}^z ) + ( - 1)^s \operatorname{Li}_s ( - {\rm e}^{ - z} ) & \sim - \frac{{z^s }}{{\Gamma (s + 1)}} - 2z^s \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\eta (2k)}}{{\Gamma (s - 2k + 1)}}\frac{1}{{z^{2k} }}} \\ & =  - 2z^s \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\eta (2k)}}{{\Gamma (s - 2k + 1)}}\frac{1}{{z^{2k} }}} ,
\end{align*}
as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{\pi}{2}$). In this sector, it is easy to see that
$$
\operatorname{Li}_s ( - {\rm e}^{ - z} ) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - kz} }}{{k^s }}}  = \mathcal{O}({\rm e}^{ - z} ).
$$
The justification of the term-by-term integration process is similar to that of Watson's lemma.
Addendum. Here is a derivation of the integral representation:
\begin{align*}
 &-\left(\operatorname{Li}_s ( - {\rm e}^z ) + ( - 1)^s \operatorname{Li}_s ( - {\rm e}^{ - z} )\right) \\ &
= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^{t-z} + 1} \mathrm{d}t 
  + (-1)^s \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^{t+z} + 1} \mathrm{d}t \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_{-z}^{+\infty} \frac{(z+x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x 
  - \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_z^{+\infty} \frac{(z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(z+x)^{s-1} - (z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x 
  + \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_{-z}^0 \frac{(z+x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x 
 \\ & \quad\; + \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^z \frac{(z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(z+x)^{s-1} - (z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x 
  + \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^z \frac{(z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^{-x} + 1} \mathrm{d}x 
  \\ & \quad\;+ \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^z \frac{(z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(z+x)^{s-1}- (z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x 
  + \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^z (z-x)^{s-1} \mathrm{d}x \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(z+x)^{s-1} - (z-x)^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^x + 1} \mathrm{d}x 
  + \frac{z^s}{\Gamma(s+1)}. 
\end{align*}

Is there a sign error in the second equation of Section $11$ of Wood's paper? After splitting the range of integration about $t=u$, I get
$$\int_0^u\frac{t^{p-1}}{{\rm e}^{t-w}+1}\ {\rm d}t =\int_0^{u}\frac{t^{p-1}{\rm e}^{w-t}}{{\rm e}^{w-t}+1}\ {\rm d}t  \= \int_0^u \frac{t^{p-1}({\rm e} ^{w-t}+1-1)}{{\rm e}^{w-t}+1}\ {\rm d}t=\int_0^u t^{p-1}\ {\rm d}t\color{red}{-}\int_0^u \frac{t^{p-1}}{{\rm e}^{w-t}+1}\ {\rm d} t.$$

Now that I have taken a closer look at it, there are many more serioues issues there. Like how the upper limit of the $t^{p-1}$ integral becomes $w$. Or how the limits of integrations are completely off after the change of variables.

Yes, I completely agree. I've been stumped by the change of variable he makes for the past 2 days. Thank you for confirming that.

In that case, the proof is flawed. Yet, this is the only paper I've found which proves the bound. Do you know of others?

@bob I added a derivation for the integral representation. This should complete the proof.

Thank you! I will have a close look when I can, and award you the answer when I do.
